# "z" sound, which to choose?

Tags: pronunciation, dialects

I've read about if "z" sound is pronounced /z/ or /dz/ and found the answer here that:

> Typically, though not consistently, [dz] occurs at the beginning of a word or in the middle of a word immediately following a syllable-final consonant (§5.1, §5.6), and [z] occurs in the middle of a word immediately following a vowel.

So I thought: okay I need to just remember which word uses which sound.
Then I heard native speakers saying:

> 絶対にだめです。with /z/ sound
>
> そんなことは絶対できないじょ。 with /dz/ sound

So seems like the SAME word can have both pronunciations, depending on person?

My question is should I care at all? Maybe I should choose one sound /z/ or /dz/ and use it in every word? Will everyone be able to understand me?

Thanks for help :)

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/8324/5010 (see alexandrec's answer)

Comment: Note also that different dialects have different realizations. I had one student from southwest Japan who insisted that his name こじま be pronounced //kozima//, in contrast to ふじむら (from older spelling ふぢむら) which he pronounced //ɸud͡ʑimura//.  Most of his classmates from the Kantō region didn't distinguish じ //zi// from ぢ //d͡ʑi//, mostly pronouncing it as //d͡ʑi// and not hearing the difference used by the one fellow from the southwest.  See [the _Yotsugana_ Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yotsugana).  I suspect the //ze// ↔ //d͡ze// alternation you're hearing might be related.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not have to remember which word uses which. If you wish, you can stick to either [dz] or [z], and everyone will understand you. If you care, it may be better to follow the rule described in [the answer you saw](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/18095/5010). As the answer says, in modern standard Japanese, [dz] and [z] are the variants (allophones) of the same sound (phoneme). That is, even if you may hear a native Japanese speaker say both [dz] and [z] depending on the situation, they are usually totally unaware of this fact, and they cannot even hear the difference. Please read the following questions.

- [Why doesn't Japanese have a special Katakana form for "hu"?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/16266/5010)
- [Why do Japanese speakers have difficulty pronouncing "L"?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/8324/5010)

  > You'll find the same thing with z/dz. Ask a Japanese if you should say zettai (with a z) and they'll say yes. Ask again if it's dzettai (with dz) and they'll also say yes. Ask which they prefer and they'll tell you they only heard one pronunciation, even though you clearly said z in one case and dz in the other.
- [Confusion with pronounciation in some words: 'm' and 'n' sounds when there is 'g'](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/54535/5010)

Actually, [dz] and [z] were distinguished in old Japanese, and the distinction is still more or less preserved in some dialects (see [Yotsugana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yotsugana)). But this is not something ordinary speakers need to worry about.

Comment: Thanks now that is a great answer! Yeah I won't really care too much and just repeat the common word pronunciation if it doesn't make really any difference to native speakers, thanks! You're great sensei, sir.